# Ansible gather facts about hosts not included in current role

Tags: ansible

I am currently writing an ansible role which is applied to a group called `master`. This role needs access to some hostvars from the group `worker`. But ansible is not executing a fact check for the children of the `worker` group since the role itself is applied to the master group.

Any ideas of how to solve this in a 'clean' way

```
- name: Configure masters
  hosts: master
  roles:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to gather the facts from the needed machines before you can access them:

```
- name: Gather facts from workers
  hosts: worker

- name: Configure masters
  hosts: master
  roles:
    - master
```

This is only replying to your direct question. Having a role (which by definition should be portable) depending on gathering facts on a specific group is IMHO a symptom of a design problem.

Comment: Yes you are right haven't thought about this design flaw yet. I'll try your solution and then refactor it.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. But I will still refactor it to get rid of the design flaw :) Thnx a lot

Comment: Note that the gather_facts stage is only calling the `setup` module. You can easilly do that manually on a given group using delegate_to in a task if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But after my refactoring I don't this anymore